# Cannot edit MySQL table from Excel

Tags: mysql, excel

I've got a table in MySQL with a non-null primary key field. I've selected within an Excel file the option to edit the database table. When entering data into a cell and selecting to "Commit" my changes, I get an error and the change does not go through.

I've tried deleting the tab and trying again, or trying with a completely new Excel file, and neither approach works.

When looking at the SQL string which is sent to the database it is very confusing to me. Essentially, the statement is a standard

```
UPDATE db_name.table_name 
SET 'change_col' = "new_val"
WHERE <where clause>
```

except that the `<where clause>` is nuts. The first operand is what I'd like, i.e. equality of the primary key on the value corresponding to the edited row, but then a huge mess of nested conjunctions and disjunctions on the other fields follows. And it isn't what you might expect. For example, I've got a `trans_num` field and on the edited row its value is `22`. So for some reason the `<where-clause>` contains

```
AND ((22 IS NULL AND `trans_num` IS NULL) OR `trans_num`=22)
```

which is quite bizarre.

I haven't seen any questions like this online, so I'm not sure what could be causing this behavior or how it can be fixed.

Comment: Have you sorted this problem? I see your post is one month old. Same issue here. This MySQL for Excel add-on doesn't use the primary keys in the where clause, which is very bad programming.

Comment: a question: is your trans_num field a floating number or an int in the MySQL DB? I believe this ``trans_num`=22` might induce the error if it's stored as 21.9999 on your DB. But even without the error, te where clause shouldn't be so "nuts" as you said.

Comment: Hey @Wli, I've been away so sorry for the delayed response. No, I didn't get this working. As for the "trans_num" field it is an integer in the database. I hope this helps (and that this issue gets solved).

Comment: Hi! Well I have posted on the mysql website (bug #87814). Status is "verified", no idea what that stands for. But the technician could reproduce it. Meanwhile I'll tell my users to use an alternative software, like HeidiSQL.